# How can I make the cursor in VS Code use the arrow keys in the same way as vim?

Tags: keyboard, vim, visual-studio-code, cursor, typing

Specifically, I want it in VS Code so that when I move the arrow key to the right at the end of a line of text it just stops in place instead of jumping to the beginning of the next line. I find this very useful in vim as I can get to the end of lines quickly by holding the arrow down without needing to backpeddle when I jump to the next line. This could probably be fixed by just getting accustomed to using the end key, but as I'm already accustomed to vim it just feels more natural this way. That being said there are a huge number of settings in VS code and I'm not sure what terms to search for to find this.

Comment: Actually, the vim way would be to use `$`, not to hold the arrow key.

Comment: @PhilippLudwig I'm not great at vim. I just like using it.